# How to report on serialized data in a custom field on Opportunities?

Tags: salesforce, report

I added a custom field (Long text) to Opportunities called 'Month_Breakdown'. It carries data like:   'Jan=10000&Feb=50000&Jun=20000&Dec=89000'.  I would like to have a report that shows opportunities grouped by Month. Hopefully which I can export later as a PDF or excel. Please take a look at screen shot. [image]

Basically would like to go through all the opportunities and present the report. So far I created a custom report with 'Opportunities' as the primary object. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off swapping the rows and columns and adding your Month_Breakdown__c field as the group by rows. You can then put in the Booked, Starting at Risk and Out For Signature as the columns. Finally, you can create a Summary Column by clicking the down arrow next to columns and selecting "Add Summary Formula". Your formula can be something like BOOKED__c:SUM + STARTING_AT_RISK__C:SUM + OUT_FOR_SIGNATURE__C:SUM.